# Access denied after creating site collection by using Powershell

Tags: powershell, 2013, site-collection, web-application

I am using SP2013 single server dev environment. I use following scripts for creating web application and site collection. but when I browse to it, it says this site has not been shared with you. I am Administrator and logged on as Administrator and cleaned all cache services.

```
$appPoolAccount = "dev\sp_service"
New-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool $appPool -ApplicationPoolAccount $appPoolAccount -Name $name -DatabaseName $dataBaseName -Url $url -Port $port -HostHeader $hostHeader -AuthenticationMethod "NTLM"

$domainAnduser = "dev\Administrator"
New-SPSite -Url $url -OwnerAlias $domainAnduser -Name $name -Template $template -Language 1033
```

It works if I do all above via CA.

Answer (score 4):

If your web application is in Claims mode (uses Claims based authentication, CBA), you need to grant permission for username that is in claims format, like *i:0#.w|dev\administrator*. More info [here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, why it works when you create the web app and sc from CA?

Comment: Because when your doing it from CA you resolve the inputted login names (sharepoint maps your input to an existing ad user)